# how to solve = Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported`?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-test

After upgrading to Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1, the application is not compiling. It shows

> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined

I have set all the activity with android:exported="false". But it is still showing this issue.

My manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.something">
 <application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:label="something"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        >

        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"

          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
       

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My gradle file:

```
 def localProperties = new Properties()
  def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
  if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
   }
}  

 def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
 if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw  GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in 
 the local.properties file.")
 }

 def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
 if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
   flutterVersionCode = '11'
 }

 def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
  if (flutterVersionName == null) {
   flutterVersionName = '11.0'
  }

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
 apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
 if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
 keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

 android {

    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
     main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

   defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
    (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.something.something1.com"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
   }
   signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? 
    file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

 }

   flutter {
     source '../..'
}

   dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: need to set android:exported="true" in your menifest activity MainActivity

Comment: if you're not using android 12 remove the android: exported flag.

Comment: I removed the android: exported flag because the android version is android tiramisu. It is showing the same error again.

Comment: Setting android: exported="true" produces the same error.

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1**

You need to set `android:exported` to either `true` or `false` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.(which you have done)

**OPTION 2**

1. Downgrade your project to an older SDK version, then rebuild project.
2. After a successful build, open your project's `AndroidManifest.xml`.
3. Click on the Merged Manifest tab at the bottom of the file and search for any `<activity>` that includes an `<intent-filter>` tag and is missing the `android:exported` attribute
4. To confirm that these activities are the issue, add them directly to your project's `AndroidManifest.xml` file with the missing android:exported attribute added and try rebuilding the project.

If `<activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity">` is missing the `android:exported` attribute, add it to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**OPTION 3**

You are using a library that doesn't target Android 12 yet. You can either upgrade the version if there is or remove it.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried setting the value to both true and false, and both resulted in errors.

Comment: Option 2 didn't work for me.

Comment: I reinstalled Android Studio and now it's the older version of Android Studio. still giving the same error. Option 3 didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using other packages or libraries, some of these libraries may not have set `android:exported=”false” or android:exported=”true”` in their Manifest files.

If you do not want to update those packages to the latest, we will have to over-ride their manifest files in the app's Manifest file.

So Step 1 is to find which package/libraries manifest files are missing the `android:exported=”false” or android:exported=”true”` .

This is done by downgrading your `targetSdkVersion` to 30 so that it compiles correctly. When the app compiles correctly it will generate a mergedManifest file in

```
build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml and 
build/app/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Step2: After you find the services / packages missing the `android:exported=”false” or android:exported=”true”`, we will copy those activities directly to `app/src/res/AndroidManifest.xml` and add in `android:exported=”false” or android:exported=”true”`.

Comment: yo..! man you are life a saver. i have strucked this issue with 3 days. Luckily found your answer. God bless you..!

Answer (score -3):

If you got this messages from your android studio, in your main activity add in android:exported=”false” or android:exported=”true” will solved this issue.

Comment: I have already added adnroid:exported value. It was giving an error.